# Vim search in C/C++ code lines

Tags: vim

Is there any way to search a string in a C/C++ source file while skipping commented lines?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is an intriguing question.

I think @sixtyfootersdude has the right idea -- let Vim's syntax highlighting tell you what's a comment and what's not, and then search for matches within the non-comments.

Let's start with a function that mimics Vim's built-in `search()` routine, but also provides a "skip" parameter to let it ignore some matches:

```
function! SearchWithSkip(pattern, flags, stopline, timeout, skip)
"
" Returns true if a match is found for {pattern}, but ignores matches
" where {skip} evaluates to false. This allows you to do nifty things
" like, say, only matching outside comments, only on odd-numbered lines,
" or whatever else you like.
"
" Mimics the built-in search() function, but adds a {skip} expression
" like that available in searchpair() and searchpairpos().
" (See the Vim help on search() for details of the other parameters.)
" 
    " Note the current position, so that if there are no unskipped
    " matches, the cursor can be restored to this location.
    "
    let l:matchpos = getpos('.')

    " Loop as long as {pattern} continues to be found.
    "
    while search(a:pattern, a:flags, a:stopline, a:timeout) > 0

        " If {skip} is true, ignore this match and continue searching.
        "
        if eval(a:skip)
            continue
        endif

        " If we get here, {pattern} was found and {skip} is false,
        " so this is a match we don't want to ignore. Update the
        " match position and stop searching.
        " 
        let l:matchpos = getpos('.')
        break

    endwhile

    " Jump to the position of the unskipped match, or to the original
    " position if there wasn't one.
    "
    call setpos('.', l:matchpos)

endfunction
```

Here are a couple of functions that build on `SearchWithSkip()` to implement syntax-sensitive searches:

```
function! SearchOutside(synName, pattern)
"
" Searches for the specified pattern, but skips matches that
" exist within the specified syntax region.
"
    call SearchWithSkip(a:pattern, '', '', '',
        \ 'synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 0), "name") =~? "' . a:synName . '"' )

endfunction


function! SearchInside(synName, pattern)
"
" Searches for the specified pattern, but skips matches that don't
" exist within the specified syntax region.
"
    call SearchWithSkip(a:pattern, '', '', '',
        \ 'synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 0), "name") !~? "' . a:synName . '"' )

endfunction
```

Here are commands that make the syntax-sensitive search functions easier to use:

```
command! -nargs=+ -complete=command SearchOutside call SearchOutside(<f-args>)
command! -nargs=+ -complete=command SearchInside  call SearchInside(<f-args>)
```

That was a long way to go, but now we can do stuff like this:

```
:SearchInside String hello
```

That searches for `hello`, but only within text that Vim considers a string.

And (finally!) this searches for `double` everywhere except comments:

```
:SearchOutside Comment double
```

To repeat a search, use the `@:` macro to execute the same command repeatedly, like pressing `n` to repeat a search.

(Thanks for asking this question, by the way. Now that I've built these routines, I expect to use them a lot.)

Comment: Thank your for your *great* answer. I expect to use them a lot as well :-)

Comment: This is great! There's one small problem, though. If your search string is found in the file, but only in places that get skipped, you get an infinite loop. You can fix it by putting a guard in place. Above the loop: `let l:guard = []`. Then in the loop: `if l:guard == [] | let l:guard = getpos('.') | elseif l:guard == getpos('.') | break | endif`.

Comment: This is really great. Note that you can exclude multiple SynNames with `SearchOutside Comment\\\\|String double`, yes you need four backslashes to escape the pipe.

Comment: @KurtHutchinson It is important to note that that solution does not work when searching with the 'c' flag, which means accept a match at the cursor position. In that case it will stop searching after the first match.

Comment: A solution for this is to do: `let l:flags = a:flags` change the search call to `l:flags` and add a line in `if l:firstmatch == []` like this: `let l:flags = substitute(l:flags, 'c', '', '')`

Answer (score 7):

This pattern searches for a string that is not preceded by the two C++ commenting conventions. I've also excluded '*' as the first non-whitespace character, as that's a common convention for multi-line comments.

```
/\(\(\/\*\|\/\/\|^\s*\*[^/]\).*\)\@<!foo
```

Only the first and fourth foo are matched.

```
foo
/* foo
* baz foo
*/ foo
// bar baz foo
```

---

Putting \v at the beginning of the pattern eliminates a bunch of backslashes:

```
/\v((\/\*|\/\/|^\s*\*[^/]).*)@<!foo
```

---

You can bind a hotkey to this pattern by putting this in your .vimrc

```
"ctrl+s to search uncommented code
noremap <c-s> <c-o>/\v((\/\*\|\/\/\|^\s*\*[^/]).*)@<!
```

Comment: not working with some comments /* */ comment without a star at beginning of line.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is helpful but when you type `:syn` it has all the formatting that is used in your file type.  Maybe you can refer to that somehow.  You could say something like:

```
map n betterN

function betterN{
  n keystroke
  while currentLine matches comment class
    do another n keystroke
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would proceed:

1. Delete all C/C++ comments (using the *replace* command `%s`)
2. Proceed to the search using *regular search* command `/`
3. Set a *mark* at the position using `m a` (to set the mark "a")
4. Undo the deletion of the comments using `u`
5. Jump to the mark "a" using ``a`
6. Eventually deleting the mark using `delm a` (it would be overwritten in the case you don't delete it, so no big deal)

Of course you can do that in one big operation/function. I do not master Vim scripting good enough to give an example of that though.

I admit my solution is a bit "lazy" (and you can probably do it *way* better) but that's all I came to.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I hope there's a more suitable way, but better that nothing... :-)

Comment: Pretty dangerous if you ask me.

Comment: @Ken Bloom: A life without danger must be pretty boring no ?! ;)