# vim search and replace only on non-commented lines

Tags: vim, replace, syntax, full-text-search

I am trying to search and replace only in non-commented line.

By non commented line, I mean lines that are not greyed out by the vim syntax highlighting.

For example:

```cpp
/*
...
DO NOT REPLACE
....
*/
```

Should not be searched and replaced.
My problem is specific to C++ but could be expanded to any language if there is a way to use the "syntax engine" of vim.

Edit : The link is only about searching, nothing about replacing.

Comment: May be duplicate  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683521/vim-search-in-c-c-code-lines

Comment: If you can fold your comments, you can close them and use `:folddoopen s/foo/bar/gc`.

Comment: folded region are search and replaced by vim

Comment: No, not with `:folddoopen`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, i will try to automatize all that.

Comment: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=848 should be able to do it for me, if i succeed in using it, wich is not the case for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally done it myself using [Bill Odom code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2696143/1416930) as a base :

```
function Repl(pattern, patternSub)

    " Move to top of the file
    normal 1G

    " Search Pattern, no wrap
    while search(a:pattern, "W", "", "") > 0

        " If found pattern is a comment, skip
        if eval(synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 0), "name") =~? "Comment")
            continue
        endif

        " If found pattern is a string, skip
        if eval(synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 0), "name") =~? "String")
            continue
        endif

        " Replace pattern by it's substitute
        exec '.s/'.a:pattern.'/'.a:patternSub.'/'

        " Restore cursor position
        normal ``
    endwhile
endfunction

command! -nargs=+ -complete=command Repl call Repl(<args>)
```

It does not replace any occurence of pattern which is a Comment or a String.
It actually is language independent.

You have to use it this way ( eg: removing space after all non-commented parenthesis ):

```
:Repl '( *','('
```